# What does "in the corner, undone" mean?

Tags: british-english

(I'm guessing this is some British slang for being in jail or dead?)

From the lyrics of Mika's "Dr. John":

> I look for joy in a strange place
>
> From the back of the bar
>
> From afar I see the look on my mama's face
>
> When her son's **in the corner, undone**
>
> She says that my life is over
>
> "Boy, you don't know what you got till it's gone
>
> Come put your head upon my shoulder"
>
> She gave me her hand, but I ignored her

Comment: If it is British slang, all I can say is that it is not in general currency.

Answer (score 1):

> formal or humorous (Of a person) ruined by a disastrous or devastating setback or reverse:

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/undone